# Generate PDF with C++ and Latex

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, latex

Would it be possible to generate PDF from c++ source code using latex ?
I´m currently using html, QWebEngine and QPrinter to create PDF.
But there is some issues like pages jump. Latex will be a good solution to ensure some graphics element are well rendered.

Working with Windows only. Crossplatform solution is not needed

Comment: I've done exactly what you have done before using QT -> HTML -> PDF but from what I remembered it was fairly bland. If you are open to changing languages I have had success running [PythonTex](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex). I used it as an automated notebook system which interacted with git history. I haven't done enough research to share alternative methods for generating PDF from C++ besides QT.

Comment: @KJ any lightweight solution might do the jobs. My need is only few titles/tables/png images. Then yes, I don´t want Gigabytes of TeX dependencies.

Comment: @Frebreeze good to know, I will consider to create a dll from python code and use it from c++ code. How many Gb is PythonTex ?

I just edited the question specifying the platforrm. Working only for Windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I did to setup pythontex on my windows 10 system.

1. [Download Miktex](https://miktex.org/download)
2. Run Executable

   - Install time: ~5 minutes on a 16gB Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1505M v5 @ 2.80GHz, 2801 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
   - Miktex base size ~10mB at **/appdata/local/miktex/*. Note, this may not be where al the files are located. IDK
3. Test if pdf latex is installed. Open terminal and type pdflatex
4. Download and extract [pythontex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex)
5. Read instructions at pythontex.pdf.
6. Install python tex using pythontex_install.bat
7. Add pythontex to path.
8. Run a pythontex [example](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/python_in_latex/index.htm)

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt]{article}%

   \usepackage{pythontex}

   \usepackage{nopageno}  

   \begin{document}

   \begin{pyconsole}

   x = 987.27
   x = x**2
   \end{pyconsole}

   The variable is $x=\pycon{x}$
   \end{document}
   ```

In order to compile do

```
  pdflatex my-latex.tex
  pythontex my-latex.tex
  pdflatex my-latex.tex
```

8. May need to install additional package for it to compile. My ending size in apdata/local grew alot.... 814 MB